# read .xlsx without Excel and OLEDB

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, excel-2007

Is there any chance to read .xlsx files in C# without having Excel installed on the client, and with no OLEDB connection available?

The application is a Winforms project written in VS2005 C# .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: What does "read" actually mean? What are you trying to do with the file? Extract data? Read document properties? Any modifications? Display or print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to use the the [Excel Data Reader on CodePlex](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This Library Doesn´t work under Medium-Trust according to http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/discussions/205317

Comment: Beware this library... I used it until I found some bugs parsing more advanced formats (hyperlinked emails).

Comment: Excellent class.. really easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

How about this one here:

[EPPlus-Create advanced Excel 2007 spreadsheets on the server](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007 files using the **Open Office Xml** format (**xlsx**).
EPPlus supports ranges, cell styling, charts, pictures, shapes, named ranges, autofilters and a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Koogra](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/) can read .xlsx files.

Comment: I did a lot of searching for similar and I found Koogra to be the most reliable, free solution that handles .xls and .xlsx and doesn't require any install/dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/). For now it supports only xls, but xlsx support is planned for the future.

Comment: unfortunately I need Xlsx-Files noct Xls

Answer (score 0):

This question looks to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925889/net-excel-file-parser/2926134#2926134) no?

Have you checked [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) ?

Best

Comment: http://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/6108 - this is the bug tracker item for XLSX support in NPOI.  No support for the format requested would make it a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

We use [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) successfully in our projects.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some 3rd party components that can help you.

[Here's one](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/xlsio)

[Here's another](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/infragisticsexcel.aspx#Overview)

Answer (score 0):

NPOI's latest version support both xsl and xslx. Download it from

[NPOI 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/downloads/list)
and use NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook fro xlsx.