# How to save excel chart as an image using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

I have **excel files** which contains few charts, and I must display these charts on the web page. Additionally I can't install **excel** on server machine.

I've checked the following free libraries:

`epplus, closedxml, spreadsheetlight`.

But they are not support that kind of operation.

Do you know any free library which can help me with that?

Comment: You can use `Save As` to save it page/selection as a `Webpage`. Then display this webpage on your website

Comment: Yes I can do that, but the excel will be downloded from some server. Then after download I need to export excel to html - I'm checking if any free library can do that.

Comment: Then have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106062/read-xlsx-without-excel-and-oledb

Comment: They described there all free libraries for excel. Should I check them all or look at the specyfic answer?

Comment: that is up to you, you want to save excel charts. So look for the library which supports that and also works nicely with your setup. I havent used any so I cannot suggest you one or the other.

Comment: Only the NPOI allows to convert excel to html. They added that functionality in version 2.0 Beta 1 [v2.0.1] (Feb, 2013) but this feature is available only to XLS file, so XLSX is not supported.

Comment: You dont have to have the library convert it for you...once the library gives you the data, you can display it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put this here in case there are no other responses...

Without Excel and therefore interop -- you could have it extract the chart XML files from the XLXS (as if it were a ZIP) to parse/recreate the charts (possibly using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting?) and then save.